# Your weekend bite-sized cryptic

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Just a mediocre 5x5 cryptic. Nothing fancy, no theme, and hopefully I didn't do anything funky with the conventions of cryptic clues.

[image: 5x5 crossword grid, with three evenly-spaced out 5-letter words going across and three going down]

**Clues:**
1A  Nothing held by fake-rich group (5)
4A  Code from an alien: "Hello, Charlie" (5)
5A  Band separates, retiring (5)

1D  Coast announced services (5)
2D  Operator embracing the alternative (5)
3D  Sum up essentials of pure capitalism (5)

As always, feedback is appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image: The completed 5x5 cryptic grid, with CHOIR, ETHIC, and STRAP across, and CREWS, OTHER, and RECAP down]

The clue explanations:

> 1A CH{O}IR* | Nothing held by fake-rich group (5)
>  4A ET+HI+C | Code from an alien: "Hello, Charlie" (5)
>  5A STRAP< | Band separates, retiring (5)
>
>  1D CREWS~CRUISE | Coast announced services (5)
>  2D O{THE}R | Operator embracing the alternative (5)
>  3D puRE CAPitalism | Sum up essentials of pure capitalism (5)
>
>  For 2D, I'm not sure if "operator" in the telecommunications sense clues "or", but regardless, "or" is a logical operator.

Feedback:

> This is a really neat puzzle! A good mix of clue types used, and the surfaces are all nice. I wasn't super sure about "services" as a definition for "crews", but [apparently](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/crew.html), a crew in the sense of a "group of advisers, assistants, or others accompanying an important person" can also be called a service, so I think that it checks out. :)

Comment: Thanks! My intended meaning for "crews" was as a verb - see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crew), scroll down. And "operator" was indeed mean to be a logical operator.

Comment: @bobble In that case, it definitely checks out! :D

Comment: How does 5A work?

Comment: @justhalf "separates" is a synonym for "parts" (as in 'parts ways', e.g. at a relationship break-up); "retiring" implies a [reversal](https://cryptics.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_reversal_indicators). And a strap is equivalent to a belt or band of material :)